# How are flags handled by the community?

Tags: support, flagging

I was going through my helpful flags, when I came across this question I flagged:
[How to approach $\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\tan^{-1}\alpha x\tan^{-1}\beta x}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3730484/how-to-approach-int-limits-0-infty-frac-tan-1-alpha-x-tan-1-beta-xx)
[image]

Notice how the question isn't closed, even though my flag is a helpful flag. What does it mean exactly when a flag is helpful, and how exactly do helpful flags get questions closed?

Comment: Also please read [Guidance for how and when to fag a question: declined flags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8684/guidance-for-how-and-when-to-flag-a-question-declined-flags?rq=1)

Comment: SomeGuy: Please review former meta posts prior to reasking questions previously answered elsewhere. You're sort of making a habit of asking duplicate questions on meta.

Comment: And if you review older posts, before asking, include that context in any such post you think did not answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A closure flag is marked helpful if the question is closed, or if (after you raised the flag) [at least one user with the close vote privilege voted to close it and used the same top-level reason as you did](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299041/295232). ('Not suitable for this site' is a top-level reason; for example, it doesn't matter if you chose 'Missing context or other details' and the close voter chose 'Seeking personal advice'.)

Other kinds of flag are marked helpful in other ways, e.g. a Very Low Quality flag on an answer is marked helpful if it's deleted or somebody edits it.